# Visual Studio create ZIP on branching (build process?)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, branch, build-process

Let's say I got a TFS with a team project and in this team project I got many folders (projects). In every project I got a branching structure so I have the folders main, servicing, hotfix and release.

I need to create a zip file whenever I take a branch to the 'release'-folder. 
Is there a way to create a zip file from a project in my 'release' directory within the branch process?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: In our company we are developing plugins for the shop system shopware. To install a plugin in the shop you need to upload a zip-archive and we want to create such a zip-archive on taking a branch to the release folder

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to zip file during or after the merge. It's impossible.

What you can do is zip files of the build output. And then copy to the release folder.

You need to add a PowerShell script to achieve it.

- For XAML build :Add the post script
- For VNext build: Add the powershell script step

Access the variables using `$env:`. The drop location would be `$env:TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION`

A example:

```
 function create-7zip([String] $aDirectory, [String] $aZipfile){
    [string]$pathToZipExe = "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", "$aZipfile", "$aDirectory";
    & $pathToZipExe $arguments;
}

create-7zip "$Env:TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY\x86\Release\*" "$Env:TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION\x86\Installer.zip"

create-7zip "$Env:TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY\x64\Release\*" "$Env:TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION\x64\Installer.zip"
```